# IP allocation in gprs

Tags: ip, gprs

I have been searching on internet about IP allocation in gprs device, every time it says hour mobile device gets a private IP but when I am connecting my mobile to internet via gprs I am getting public IP 100.106.x.x which changes every time I switch off and on mobile data.

Can anyone help me with that ???

Answer (score 0):

The public IP address is actually not of your own device, the public IP address is of the device which gives you a NAT IP to your mobile device.